# Controlling the highlight color

Tags: rxvt

I setup `rxvt-unicode` and I also installed a plugin to do code folding.

[image]

The image above is of my terminal, you see the folds in the code the problem is that grey line, it's always that color and it clashes with my underlying text.

Other than that highlighted line eveything else looks fine, is it possible to change the color of the highlighted lines to make the contrast with the text more?

Comment: I don't understand the down vote but whatever.

Comment: How is not mentioning anywhere the name of the software that you are using going to help other people with a similar problem in the future?  Humans can _guess_ from the screenshot, but text search engines do not make guesses from pictures.

Comment: The code was edited by SE staff but even before the edits, the first line said rxvt-unicode and it was tagged rxvt. Was that enough to get a downvote?

Comment: That's not the software being shown, nor is it where you installed your plugins, nor is it what is doing the code folding, nor indeed is it the locus of of the problem.  **That** software, in contrast, gets no mention at all.  This isn't a personal help site.  Questions and answers have to be useful to other people, too.  If they cannot even find the question, because it isn't discoverable under the name of the software, this is of zero use to them.

Comment: @JdeBP well, AlexP was able to help me sort it out and point me in the right direction. I appreciate your feedback though, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim gives you full control over the colors used in the character-cell and graphical interfaces. See `:help coloring`, `:help colorscheme` and `:help highlight` in Vim. In particular, you want to `:highlight Folded ctermfg=... ctermbg=...` or `:highlight Folded guifg=... guibg=...` depending on whether you are using the character-cell or the graphical interface.

Comment: This was it, in my case changing the ctermbg was the one that did it. Thanks a lot!